# Any guidance on learning rate / batch size for noisy data (high Bayes error rate)?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, optimization

Is there any guidance available for training on very noisy data, when Bayes error rate (lowest possible error rate for any classifier) is high? For example, I wonder if deliberately (not due to memory or numerical stability limitations) lowering the batch size or learning rate could produce a better classifier.

I found so far some general recommendations, not specific for noisy data: [Tradeoff batch size vs. number of iterations to train a neural network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164876/tradeoff-batch-size-vs-number-of-iterations-to-train-a-neural-network)

Comment: Shouldn't it be the contrary? Batch learning is used as it cancels out noise due to all the samples taken...Whereas in the extreme case of batch Learning where batch size = 1 also called online learning results in very shaky convergence with spikes in loss.